# try/except while true in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, exception

The following code will gather data from an API and the try/except clause will help to handle several errors (from authentication, index, anything).
There's only one error (an authentication error) that I'm using the `while True` to repeat the API call to make sure I get the data and it will after a try or two. However if by any means I get another error, it'll be infinitely looping and I can't break it so it goes to the next iteration. I tried to create a counter and if the counter reaches to a number then (`pass` or `continue` or `break`) but it's not working.

```
## Create a array to loop to:
data_array_query = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date,freq='6H')

#This is my idea but is not working
#Create a counter
counter = 0

#Loop through the just created array
for idx in range(len(data_array_query)-1):
    ## If counter reaches move on to next for loop element
    while True:
        if counter>=5:
            break
        else:
            try:
                start_date  = data_array_query[idx]
                end_date = data_array_query[idx+1]

                print('from',start_date,'to',end_date)

                df = api.query(domain, site_slug, resolution, data_series_collection, start_date=str(start_date), end_date=str(end_date), env='prod', from_archive=True, phase='production').sort_index()
                print(df.info())
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                counter +=1
                print(counter)
```

[image]

So the output of running this code for a couple of days show that when it runs 5 times (that's the counter max I set up) it does break but it breaks the whole loop and I only want it to move to the next date.

Any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a break statement to get out of a while True loop. pass and continue work for for loops that have a fixed number of iterations. While loops can go on forever (hence the different names)

Comment: @JuanHurtado python shouldn't behave like this. Are you sure you did it right?

Comment: @MichaelHofmann you are right. I actually forgot to reset the counter to 0 again. That solved everything.